# designing nested class structure for rest api using rest sharp

Tags: c#, .net, class, rest, restsharp

I am working with below mentioned structure where i have classes in that i have list of classes with a class name. Each class has its mapping.

I need to query this using rest sharp from a rest service.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
  <Response status="Success">
  <Classes>
  <Class className="Library">
  <ClassMappings>   
  < ClassMapping key="cls1" /> 
  < ClassMapping key="cls2" /> 
  < ClassMapping key="cls3" /> 
  </ ClassMappings>
  </ Class>
  < Class className="Staff">
  </ Class>
    .
    .
    .
  </Classes>
```

I have designed this classes but its not giving me mappings properly.

```
public class Class
{
    public string className { get; set; }
    //public ClassMappings Mappings { get; set; }
    public List<ClassMapping> Mappings { get; set; }
}

public class Classes : List<Class> { }

//public class ClassMappings //: List<ClassMapping>
//{
//    public List<ClassMapping> ClassMapping { get; set; }
//}

public class ClassMapping
{
    public string key { get; set; }
}
```

You can see i have already tried the commented code also. Where class mappings is a different class.

Can anyone help me designing classes for rest call.

Thanks

Comment: You should write `<ClassMapping` instead of `< ClassMapping`, and shouldn't the array be named `ClassMappings` instead of `Mappings` ?

Comment: there is no space in <ClassMapping instead of < ClassMapping these tags. I was giving example. I can keep any class name untill it works. Right now its loading data only upto one level. Classes and Class is populated in call with class name but list as 0 item. Its not loading nested part.

Comment: As a general solution I'd load it as a generic object and then use the debugger to parse the correct structure.

Comment: thanks for the information, i was aware of it. but in hurry i just kept the wrong name.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array should be named `ClassMappings` instead of `Mappings`.

As a general solution you could load the xml as a generic object and then use the debugger to see the correct structure.